# How to map Object inside Array inside Object in Swift and Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using Swift, Alamofire, and Alamofire ObjectMapper. I have a response JSON with an array of objects inside. I need to map each of the objects inside the array to an object and put it in an array of objects.

I'm pretty much sure that its's a dumb question, but I haven't found any solution online.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use SwiftyJSON https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Then you can do something like this.. `response` is the json reponse from alamofire

```
var categories = [Category]()
if let json = response["sports"].array {

    for var i = 0; i < json.count; i++ {
        let category : JSONObj = json[i]

        if let catname = category["name"].string {
            categories.append(Category(json: json[i]))
        }
    }
}
```

In the Category model i have a `init` method that take a json as parameter.. Like this

```
class Category {

var name : String?
var id : Int?

init(json : JSONObj) {

    if let name = json["name"].string {
        self.name = name
    }

    if let id = json["id"].int {
        self.id = id
    }       
}

init() { }
}
```